# xamarin forms: button text wrap

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to text wrap in a button inside a grid, but only the first line appears, the code is:

```
grid.Children.Add(new Button {
    Text = la[0].Floor,
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
    BorderWidth = 1,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, 
} , column, row );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your `Grid.RowDefinitions`'s Height to `Auto` for what ever row that button is being placed on. Using `Auto` instead of `GridUnitType.Star` should give the `Button` as much height as it needs to show it's content.

That being said, if the text is super long, it still might not work.

If that button is on the first row, then your would change that row's `Height` to:

```
Grid grid = new Grid {
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitions {
        new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto }
    }
}
```

If that does not help, please show your `Grid`'s initialization code.